# External Hard disk Input/Output error

Tags: io, external-hdd

One of WD external harddrives is not working when I try to access some folder. I am able to access the rest of the folders on the disk. I am getting Input/Output error as show in the attached Image.
[image: error screenshot]

Also I run some `sudo` commands which I found in some of the fora, does this output help in anyway to narrow down the issue?
[image: sudo command outputs]

How can I get to my data in that particular folder.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a corruption on drive `sdb`. Before you try and repair that NTFS partition (probably best try natively under Windows) you can use `ddrescue` to make a copy of the drive, so you have something to retry in case the repair fails.

You can also use `smartctl` to check if the drive has errors, but if this drive is connected via USB you might not be able to issue the commands to the drive.

It might not be a good idea to continue using that driver after (and if) you recover the data.

Comment: My laptop doesn't have enough space to use the `ddrescue` command, which I guess take all the 2TB image file when i execute right?

Comment: @AnwerSylesh Yes, or at least the size of the partition, not necessarily the whole drive